# gulp-mocha issue in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, gulp, mocha.js, webstorm

I am trying to run tests in WebStorm using gulp-mocha. The tests are transpiled from TypeScript. I am running the standard WebStorm configuration to run gulp using node as the interpreter.

Gulp file:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'); var mocha = require('gulp-mocha');

gulp.task('default', function () {
    return gulp.src('app/**/*-spec.js', {read: false})
        // gulp-mocha needs filepaths so you can't have any plugins before it
        .pipe(mocha({reporter: 'nyan'})); });
```

Error:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WebStorm 11.0.2\bin\runnerw.exe"
>   "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"
>   C:\Users\us1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js
>   --color --gulpfile c:\dev\angular-scheduler\gulpfile.js default [13:33:22] Using gulpfile c:\dev\angular-scheduler\gulpfile.js
>   [13:33:22] Starting 'default'... [13:33:22] 'default' errored after 32
>   ms [13:33:22] ReferenceError in plugin 'gulp-mocha' Message:
>       System is not defined Stack: **ReferenceError: System is not defined**
>       at Object. (c:\dev\angular-scheduler\app\classes\builders\CalBuilder-spec.js:1:63)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
>       at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
>       at require (module.js:385:17)
>       at c:\dev\angular-scheduler\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:216:27
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at Mocha.loadFiles (c:\dev\angular-scheduler\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:213:14)
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by using commonjs in the tsc settings rather then systemjs.